# Haskell recursive program

Tags: haskell

I begin the function from here and don't know what to do next. Please help me in solving this function.

> Write a Haskell recursive function noDupl which returns True if there
> are no duplicates characters in the given string.
>
> ```
> noDupl :: String -> Bool
> noDupl = ?
> ```
>
> Example Output:
>
> ```
> noDupl "abcde"
> True
>
> noDupl "aabcdee"
> False
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've got the type signature right. Now like all recursion questions you can then think about the base case (where the recursion ends) and the recursive case (which will recurse with a smaller input).

For strings (and lists in general), the base case is usually the empty string (list). The recursive case usually takes the head of the list, processes it, then pushes to the front of the new result.

This probably sounds pretty confusing. It'll make sense when you look at some examples:

```
-- Increment each character by one (by ASCII).
incAll :: String -> String
incAll [] = [] -- Base case: empty string (list).
incAll (x:xs) = chr (ord x + 1) : incAll xs -- Recursive case, process head and prepend to recursed result.
```

There's a more concise way to write the above, but it demonstrates how recursion could be done.

Of course, you don't have to process each char individually, you could pattern match on two chars like so:

```
f (x0:x1:xs) = ...
```

(But you'll need to be careful with the base case.)

Hopefully this provides you with enough hints to write `noDupl`.